# Chaining promises with prams in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Trying to chain two promises together where one takes a param. How do I chain them? `p1().then(p2(23));` didn't work

```
function p1() {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function(){
   console.log("hey p1")
    resolve()
  }, 2000)
 })
}
function p2(b) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function(){
   console.log("hey p2: " + b)
    resolve()
  }, 2000)
 })
}

p1().then(p2(23));
```

Comment: .then expects a function as an argument

    `p1().then(() => p2(23));`

Comment: `p1().then(p2)` works fine. The problem is when I try to pass in a pram inside the p2 @JaromandaX

Comment: yes ... `p2` is not the same as `p2(23)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass function which returns promise, for example:

```
function p1() {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function(){
   console.log("hey p1")
    resolve()
  }, 2000)
 })
}
function p2(b) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function(){
   console.log("hey p2: " + b)
    resolve()
  }, 2000)
 })
}

p1()
  .then(function(){
      return p2(23)
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

I recommend using `async/await` if you're able.

I ran this in the Chrome console and it worked as expected.

```
async function p1() {
  await setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("hey p1");
  }, 2000)
}
async function p2(b) {
  await setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("hey p2: " + b)
  }, 2000)
}

p1().then(() => p2(23));
```

Comment: this is as wrong as the code in the question ... `.then` still expects a function as an argument - if anything, it's worse ... `await setTimeout` does not wait for anything

Comment: @JaromandaX you're right, `.then` expects a function, and I'm about to update my code, but it still works in the Chrome console.

Comment: `it still works` - it's an illusion - I mean, your p1 and p2 functions don't even return anything! besides, hey p1 and hey p2 get logged almost at the same time (both after 2 seconds), there should be a 2 second delay between p1 and p2!

Comment: @JaromandaX please remove downvote. I don't know the intention of the OP about when the second function should be called. You are assuming the OP wants p1 to print after 2 seconds, and then p2 to print after another 2 seconds.

Comment: I'm not assuming anything. I can see what the code in the question is doing. I can see what your code is doing. I can see that your attempt to answer is wrong

Comment: Would you kindly explain how my code is wrong? And  you are assuming that the OP wants a 2 second wait, then p1 to be called, then a 2 second wait, then p2 to be called. His code does not do that, so I'm giving him the benefit of the doubt, until I find out otherwise, that he wants to wait 2 seconds, call p1, then call p2.

Comment: `His code does not do that` - he says, in a comment that `p1().then(p2) works fine` - if you execute his code, replacing his poorly thought out last line with `p1().then(p2)` then you will see that, indeed, there is a 2 second delay before p1 is logged and another 2 second delay before p2 is logged. If you see the accepted answer, you will also note this 2 second + 2 second sequence - your use of async/await is completely inappropriate, you've removed all trace of promise chaining

Comment: i.e. `await setTimeout` does **not** wait for the timeout to expire before returning